# Best free (or very cheap) automation tool for Windows GUI testing?

Tags: automated-testing, tools

I used to use vTask Studio, but it seems they've abandoned it. No updates in almost a year.
Is there are any other automation tool for Windows GUI testing?

Comment: Whenever you ask "what is the best tool", you can expect to receive a long list of "my favorite thing" responses.  But without real. well-understood requirements, there's no assurance anyone else's favorite has any value in your shop.

Comment: Aaron, has your question been answered? Or would you like to elaborate more for a more accurate answer?

Comment: Agree with Joe Strazzere! You can refer this article that includes both free, open-source and commercial test automation solutions. https://medium.com/@briananderson2209/best-automation-testing-tools-for-2018-top-10-reviews-8a4a19f664d2

Answer (score 12):

You can try [Sikuli](http://sikuli.org/). It is a image recognition tool that you can script it with Python. If the product that you are testing is fairly stable in terms of UI, then it will be a good tool to use.

Comment: SIKULI is outstanding for WPF work as it doesn't rely on any window IDs/classes/HREFs based methods that can quickly become unstuck when testing a WPF app. It has also got the added advantage of being completely independent of the Visual Studio and the .NET environment, which is a good thing when it comes to independent testing.

Comment: The successor project is http://www.sikulix.com/

Answer (score 8):

Windows has the built in [Windows Automation API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms726294%28VS.85%29.aspx) available. Depending on what you want to do, it could get a little hairy using the APIs.  The [TestAPI](http://testapi.codeplex.com) project has some nice wrappers around UIAutomation to simplify the model.

Answer (score 3):

I use WinTask.  I'm very happy with it.
I've used AutoIT in the past, and I know lots of folks who still do.

If you refine your requirements beyond (cheap, Windows GUI), you may get more precise answers.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't used it myself because I wrote my own UIAutomation library, but [White](http://white.codeplex.com/) is an open source project from Thoughtworks that should do exactly what you are after they support  Win32, WinForms, WPF, Silverlight and SWT (Java) platforms.

For an IDE you can use [Visual Studio C# Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/), which is free for even commercial use. It lacks unit testing as an integrated feature so you would need to use something like [xUnit](http://xunit.codeplex.com/) as a test runner.

Answer (score 3):

I use Perl with Win32 Modules to do my System Administration. Also, Perl allows you to run some of the task as services, which is very handy.

Also, you would learn a lot by doing. It also depends on your requirements, learning curve and flexibility in picking up a new framework all together.

Answer (score 3):

You could try [Automa](http://www.getautoma.com). It's a young product and thus very reasonably priced in comparison to other tools on the market. It lets you use simple commands such as

```
start("notepad")
click("File", "Save")
write("Hello World", into="File name").
```

Its unique advantage is that it's very non-technical: Unlike other tools, it doesn't require knowing application-internal ids such as `"textfield1234"` or using tons of `waitFor`-commands. Like Sikuli, it also supports image recognition.

*Disclaimer:* I'm one of Automa's developers.

Comment: Looks interesting, I'm giving it a try in the next days. Thank you.

Comment: Note that this is just a trial for 30 days

Answer (score 2):

[Cobra](https://github.com/ldtp/cobra) is Free Software to automate any app (which are accessibility enabled) on Windows XP SP3 / Windows 7 / Windows 8. Open sourced by VMware Inc. LDTP is also cross platform GUI automation tool, for more information check http://ldtp.freedesktop.org

Comment: Seems you are the creator/owner ? Can you make your connection with the tool clear ?

Comment: Welcome to SQA @nagappan_alagappan - seems like you're the maintainer of this open source project? Helps to say so, until I spotted the open source bit it was setting off my spam antennae. Also it's nice to know when someone's posting about a tool they know *really* well - because they wrote it. We've got a few members of SQA who fall into that category. Hope you'll stick around to answer any questions folk have about using the tool!

Comment: Great to see an interest ! I will be happy to answer any question on this. I'm the author of Cobra / LDTP, which works on Mac and Linux, with all major language supports for writing the test. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have been using  [Macro Scheduler](http://www.mjtnet.com/index.htm) for about 9 months and have been able to do everything I have needed to do. (Automated testing of CADCAM software) I had used them previously with a different company and had great results there too.

They have an absolutely fantastic forums/support site. All messages get answered and its not uncommon to get multiple answers. The experienced users are vey willing to help newbies get up to speed.

Prices start at $100 USD. Trial downloads available.

Answer (score 0):

+1 more tool found today Approval Tests - https://github.com/approvals/ApprovalTests.Net

Approval Tests can be used for verifying objects that require more than a simple assert. They also come prepackaged with utilities for some common .Net scenarios including

Dictionaries & Collections, Long Strings, Log Files, Asp.Net, Asp.Net Mvc, Winforms, Wpf
Entity Framework, Rdlc reports

Answer (score -2):

Simple or Complex GUI Testing can be done with MurGee [Auto Mouse Clicker](http://www.murgee.com/auto-mouse-clicker/). It does have free trial and requires a licence fee of $5.00. Can automate various types of mouse clicking, keyboard typing and other stuff.

Comment: If you have a connection to the product (e.g. you work for MurGee), you should mention this in your answer.